# Does using a VAO eliminate the overhead produced by using multiple VBOs?

Tags: opengl

It is my understanding that having several VBO bind calls is not recommended since it produces overhead from the CPU. However, does binding several VBOs to one VAO, then binding that VAO reduce or completely remove the overhead from binding several VBOs, since you are letting OpenGL rebind those VBOs automatically? This is assuming that the GPU knows what to do and that OpenGL isn't doing it for you on the CPU.

I've searched around and I could not come up with any results. I am currently stuck with a OpenGL <2.1 laptop so I cannot really test for myself (yet).

Comment: Say you've two 10 VBOs of type `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, I think you can have only one of them to be remembered by a VAO i.e. the current one bound.

Comment: I'm almost certain you can have 16 or more VBOs of any type binded to a VAO and they'll all get rebinded by the VAO automatically.

Comment: Got [a reference](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/167743-VBO-to-VAO?p=1183757&viewfull=1#post1183757) which supports your claim; good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a well tuned driver implementation, I would still expect it to be more efficient if all your attributes are in the same VBO, even when using VAO. *derhass* already touched on a major aspect. Most GPUs cannot directly access memory using CPU addresses. Buffers have to be mapped into the GPU address space.

So, every time a VAO is bound, the driver has to at least check if those mappings already exist, and map the buffers that are not already mapped. There's also overhead for tracking the buffers to your draw call, to make sure that they remain mapped until the draw call finished executing. The more buffers you use, the more work is needed for all of this.

Another aspect are the memory access patterns. If your attributes are interleaved in a single buffer, you get much better memory access locality. Say you have positions and normals with 3 floats each, adding up to 24 bytes per vertex. If they are interleaved, the 24 bytes will likely be in the same cache line. If they are in two separate buffers, you could get two cache misses for a single vertex.

On the question if VAOs are more efficient:
Yes, binding a VAO should be more efficient if it's well implemented. For example, without using VAO, you typically have a bunch of `glVertexAttribPointer` calls when binding a buffer. The state passed in with these calls (size, type, stride, etc) has to be translated into GPU commands. With a VAO, the GPU commands for setting up this state can be rebuilt only when the VAO changes, and then simply reused every time the VAO is bound.

While state setup for plain VBO usage can also be well optimized, it will still take more work in the driver. You also have the overhead for making more API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Such things are completely implementation-specific. It will reduce some function calls into the driver, which might already be worth it. But how the implementation handles VAOs internally is not really predictable. The way OpenGL is designed will still lead to lots of validataion when a VAO is bound, for example an implementation will not be able to just cache the pointers to the memory which are the relevant thing for the GPU at VAO setup time, since the VBO *name* is being referenced. Since you can create a new and totally different buffer storage for the same buffer object, the implementation has to at least make sure that the buffer object is still the same as before. So there is lots of stuff do be done here, which is not going to happen on the GPU, so I would not expect a too big decrease in CPU overhead in this situation. However, I haven't profiled it...